# how to get public IP of azure scale set instance from python API azure sdk?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-sdk

I have assigned to each instance public IP (no Load Balancer ), i tried to get it's public IP from the python code but no luck, what i  try so far :

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient      
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=ID, secret=SECRET_KEY, tenant=TENANT_ID)
for net in NetworkManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID):
    print net
```

the IP is not here .
i have also tried via scale set object that returned from this :

```
vmss =  ComputeManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID).virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(resource_group_name=resource_group,
                                                                           virtual_machine_scale_set_name=scale_set_name)
```

but i don't see property of public IP in it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure of this myself so I had a look. Turns out there is an API under the virtual networks service that [lists all public IP addresses of a scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/publicipaddresses/listvirtualmachinescalesetpublicipaddresses).

This code should work for you, it'll list all of the public IP addresses in use inside of a scale set.

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

# Your Azure Subscription ID
subscription_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

rg = 'testscaleset-rg'
scaleset_name = 'testscaleset'

for i, vm in enumerate(compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(resource_group_name=rg, virtual_machine_scale_set_name=scaleset_name)):
    nic_name = (vm.network_profile.network_interfaces[0].id).split("/")[-1]
    ip_config_name = vm.network_profile_configuration \
               .network_interface_configurations[0]\
               .ip_configurations[0]\
               .name
    ip_address_name = vm.network_profile_configuration \
           .network_interface_configurations[0]\
           .ip_configurations[0]\
           .public_ip_address_configuration\
           .name
    print(vm.name, (network_client.public_ip_addresses.get_virtual_machine_scale_set_public_ip_address( \
        resource_group_name=rg, \
        virtual_machine_scale_set_name=scaleset_name,\
        virtualmachine_index=i, \
        network_interface_name=nic_name, \
        ip_configuration_name=ip_config_name, \
        public_ip_address_name=ip_address_name)).ip_address)
```

Should return

```
testscaleset_0 40.68.133.234
```